# My G-Raid Thunderbolt 3 Health & spin up time going down fast?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

My G-Raid Thunderbolt 3 Health & spin up time going down fast,im using macbook pro m1 & G-raid system in Raid 1,does anyone know the reasons ??

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is reason for alarm, this value is typically all over the place:

[image]

I see this on more of my drives, specially external ones. It may recover after next power-cycle. Spin-up time is the kind of attribute that you would expect to vary. It would depend on factors such as supply voltage (+12V) and ambient temperature. The latter would affect the viscosity of the fluid in the spindle bearing.

The "health rating" is an *interpretation* of the [maker of the DriveDx tool](https://binaryfruit.com/drivedx/help#ui-drive-health-dashboard-health-rating), without (his) further explanation it's quite meaningless IMHO. You'd almost guess he takes the lowest current normalized value and decides that's his overall health assessment.

Most significant are the "Important health indicators" in left column of your SMART tool, specially 005 and 197.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply and clarification
I came up with your explanation for some possible reasons
First, I connected the hard drive to a Thunderbolt 3 cable, as it contains data and also gives electricity to my macbook pro. It is better for me to use a USB 3 cable to obtain data only.
Secondly, I bought another hard drive ( wd mybook duo ) with Raid 1 System and placed it on top of the device, as it could also affect the temperature and also with Thunderbolt 3 cable
Do my guesses affect what happened in order to maintain the(spin up tim ) & (temperature)